# reload page until it has some element using ruby selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I have such code:

```
until @driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_cp_lblC").displayed?
  puts "invalid page solution"
  enter_page
end
```

and i need to do some method, until page will have some element with some id, now it throw's error, that selenium couldn't locate element with this id. What i do wrong, and how to solve it?

Also maybe it is easier to do with watir?

Comment: Give the full error and the respective html please. And also try this - `@driver.find_element(:css, "#ctl00_cp_lblC")` .

Comment: @Babai sorry, couldn't send all error log for privacy reasons... here is shot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/cap/cmddd.png   also default html page didn't have element with id ctl00_cp_lblC, so i reload with some logic, until it whill have it

Comment: @Babai also part of html, where it is present (also your solution didn't help) <tr id="ctl00_cp_lblNieprawidlowaCaptcha">
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <span id="ctl00_cp_lblC" class="komunikat_blad" style="color: Red;">Неправильная проверка по картинке </span><br>
                                    </td>
       </tr>

Comment: my comp policy blocked it,I couldn't see the html...

Comment: then try `@driver.find_element(:css, "span.komunikat_blad").` If it works then I will give you full ruby code..first tell me..

Comment: @Babai no, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver throws an error when an element is not found. *Displayed?* only shows whether an object is hidden or not.  As you have seen, when the object is not even in the html, a NoSuchElementFound exception occurs.

Apologies for the java but you should get the idea;

```
Boolean elementFound = false;

    do {
        getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        try {
             elementFound = getDriver().findElement(By.id("ct100_cp_lblC")).isDisplayed();

        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        }   
        getDriver().navigate().refresh();  

    } while (!elementFound);

    getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You would need extra code to stop an infinite loop but you shoudl get the idea.

This is a big difference between the Watir & WebDriver APIs, but I suppose it is whatever you are used to.

Comment: Yes, if you read my comment, it was an example to follow. It should be very easy to port over to Ruby

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, by RobbieWareham, find_element will throw an exception if the element does not exist. You want to:

1. Rescue the exception of the element not being found and call your enter_page method
2. Wrap all of that in a wait.until, so that it does not run indefinitely

This would look like:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5) # seconds
begin
  element = wait.until do
    begin
      @driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_cp_lblC")
    rescue
      enter_page
    end
  end
ensure
  @driver.quit
end
```

In Watir, it would be easier. It would simply be:

```
browser.element(:id => "ctl00_cp_lblC").wait_until_present
```

Or if you need to do stuff when the element is not present:

```
browser.wait_until(2) do
  present = browser.element(:id => "ctl00_cp_lblC").present?
  enter_page unless present 
  present
end
```

Comment: it will no present in 5 sec, or 10, it will be presented when server done some calculation, so i need page to reload

Comment: The code is basically checking for the element and then reloading the page (your enter_page method) if the element is not found. It repeats these two steps until 5 seconds is up. You could remove the wait.until, but then it would loop forever (which is bad if you have a bug in your application).

Comment: i just need to do some code (there it reloads page) until it will have some id

Comment: ok, thank's will try... also where could i find some good watir example code, with error's throwing etc.. ?